# transform second-order pde into two first-order pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab

I need to transform my equation into two first-order equation. But I don't know how to do that. My equation is the Gibbons-Tsarev equation :
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x\partial t} - \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}} + \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} +1 = 0 
\end{equation}

by posing
$y_1=u$   et   $y_2=∂u/∂t$

We have the analytical solution :
\begin{equation}
u(x,t) = \frac{c_{1}}{c_{2}} e^{c_{2}x} + \frac{x}{c_{2}} + {c_{2}} + 0.5{c_{2}} t^{2} + {c_{3}}t + {c_{4}}
\end{equation}

with: 0 $\le$ x $\le$ 2  and   0 $\le$ t $\le$ 1
and c1=c2=c3=c4=1

I need to solve this problem with matlab by using ode45.

Thank you

Comment: From the definition of $y_1,y_2$ you know that $ (y_{1})_x = u_x$ and $(y_2)_x = u_{xt}$ and so on. Substitute this into the PDE so it just has $y_1$ and $y_2$ terms. The second PDE is $(y_1)_t = y_2$ which also follows from the definition.

Comment: We have already use that method and so we have isolated the $y_{2}$ but our problem is that we can't divide by a matrix :  \begin{equation}  dy_{2}=\frac {(y_{2})_{x}*y_{2}+(y_{1})_{xx}+1}{(y_{1})_{x}}  \end{equation}

Comment: Where are you dividing by a matrix? $(y_1)_x$ is scalar function right?

Comment: u is function of x and t so it's a vector and we input that vector in $(y_{1})_{x}$

Comment: Think I might have misunderstood. You mean it's a vector in your numerical implementation right? Then its element based division (you divide the ith element of the numerator by the ith element in the denominator). Anyway in order to judge your numerical implementation you need to add it to the question

Comment: Okey i got it ! Thank you for your help